# Using Java's SunMSCAPI/Windows-MY to access smartcard certificates for TLS/SSL connection with client authentication

Tags: java, windows, ssl, smartcard, client-certificates

I have a Java application that is using the certificates from a smartcard to do TLS/SSL client authentication.
The smartcard has 2 certificates, one for signing and the other for authentication. This is how I am doing this:

```
    // loading windows-my store
    KeyStore windowsMyKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
    windowsMyKeyStore.load(null, null);
    // loading keymanager 
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(windowsMyKeyStore, null);
    // building truststore
    TrustManager[] trustAllManager = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }};
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustAllManager, new SecureRandom());
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"},
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(...);
```

The problem happens because Java select the **first** certificate (the wrong one) that matches the CertificateRequest from server, as can be seen in this extract when `-Djavax.net.debug=all`:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
matching alias: <<alias for SIGNING certificate>>
matching alias: <<alias for AUTHENTICATION certificate>> 
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
    << SIGNING certificate >> 
]
```

Is it possible to configure Java so it uses the correct certificate?

Comment: To configure _Java_ you can write your own `KeyManager` which mostly wraps the standard one but tweaks `chooseClientAlias` (and optionally `getClientAliases`) as you wish. With HttpClient you can also use `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder` (in older versions `..http.conn.ssl..`) which provides exactly such a wrapper (`KeyManagerDelegate`) that uses a `PrivateKeyStrategy` you can supply to control the alias choice.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks! I tried a lot of things! I even ended up clearing the "Windows-my store" (using certutil.exe) and installing only the correct cert. Could you please put your answer so I can accept it, then I will edit it to add the code.

Comment: I didn't do enough work for an answer, only a hint. If you developed a good answer, go right ahead; self-answers are explicitly allowed (although IIRC you may have to wait to accept) or if you want you can make it community.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, I solved it this way:

```
KeyStore windowsMyKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
windowsMyKeyStore.load(null, null);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(windowsMyKeyStore, null, new PrivateKeyStrategy() {
  @Override
  public String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket) {
    for (String alias : aliases.keySet()) {
      PrivateKeyDetails privateKeyDetails = aliases.get(alias);
      for (X509Certificate certificate : privateKeyDetails.getCertChain()) {
        try {
          certificate.checkValidity();
          List<String> extKeyUsage = certificate.getExtendedKeyUsage();
          if (extKeyUsage != null && extKeyUsage.contains("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"))
            return alias;
        } catch (CertificateExpiredException | CertificateNotYetValidException | CertificateParsingException e) {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help of @dave_thompson_085 I could solve this:

```
SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
sslContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(windowsMyKeyStore, null, new PrivateKeyStrategy() {
    @Override
    public String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket) {
        for (String alias : aliases.keySet()) {
            PrivateKeyDetails privateKeyDetails = aliases.get(alias);
            for (X509Certificate certificate : privateKeyDetails.getCertChain()) {
                if (requiredCertificate.getSerialNumber().equals(certificate.getSerialNumber())) {
                    return alias;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("required certificate not found");
    }
});
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build());
```

There are other solutions too:

- Use certutil.exe to delete all the certificates except the one is located on the card. An ugly solution but it works and solve other problems like the annoying ["Please insert your card" popup when loading the Windows-MY store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12937604/2692914).
- Use the "NewSunX509" from [Java Multiple and Dynamic Keystores (smartcards)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) that is supposed to work with smartcards. Didn't work for me.
- Build your own provider and filter it at the library level, you will need to [modify the source code of sunmscapi.dll and create your own provider](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/e7f78523d41d). Will it work? Didn't test it.

Comment: The link for "Build your own provider and filter it at the library level, you will need to modify the source code of sunmscapi.dll and create your own provider. Will it work? Didn't test it." is broken. Here's the active link - https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/e7f78523d41d.